# Android Boot Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a Service that gets started when a user logs into my app that creates alarms depending on when certain events start. The user gets a notification and can click on it to update attendance. All works great until the user turns off the phone.

I've looked at this bootcompleted example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671448/2039505) and have implemented it but would like to know what happens when the user logs into my app and starts the original service?

Is there a way i can use only one service? 
Also, in relation to the boot_completed service if the event start dates change then these alarms will potentially be incorrect.

Comment: You can check if your service has already started and if not start it (I think this is your issue). Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-android I would look at the answer with the most votes as opposed to the accepted one personally

Comment: Thanks, this really pointed me in the right direction!